# Spring DATA JPA Passing two parameters -could not extract ResultSet;SQL [n/a]; org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammerException:could not extract ResultSet

Tags: spring, oracle, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have written following spring data JPA native query.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ID, REFERENCE FROM ORDER_MATCH where ORDER_REF IN :orderRef AND STATUS = :status", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> retriveData(List<String> orderRef, String status);
```

this code gives me the following error.

```
SQL Error : 936, SQLState : 42000
ORA-00936 : missing expression
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException : could not extract ResultSet; SQL[n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammerException: could not extract ResultSet
```

However, If I removed one parameter, then code works, for example following two combinations works without any issue, problem happens when I have two parameters, could anybody help me to identify what is going wrong here. Thank you so much in advance.

working combinations with one parameter

```
@Query(value = "SELECT ID, REFERENCE FROM ORDER_MATCH where ORDER_REF IN :orderRef" , nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> retriveData(List<String> orderRef);

@Query(value = "SELECT ID, REFERENCE FROM ORDER_MATCH where STATUS = :status", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> retriveData(String status);
```

Just to add some more details, I have used :? way of passing parameters and it also results in same error

```
    @Query(value = "SELECT ID, REFERENCE FROM ORDER_MATCH where ORDER_REF IN (?1) AND STATUS = ?2", nativeQuery = true) 
List<Object[]> retriveData(List<String> orderRef, String status);
```

Comment: Have you tried logging the SQL query being actually generated?

Comment: yes, I did, it is perfectly fine sql query and I am able to run on SQL developer passing parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT ID, REFERENCE FROM ORDER_MATCH where ORDER_REF IN :orderRef AND STATUS = :status", nativeQuery = true)
List<Object[]> retriveData(@Param("orderRef") List<String> orderRef, @Param("status") String status);
```

Also please note that as it's stated in the [hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-in-predicate):

> The list of values can come from a number of different sources. In the `constructor_expression` and `collection_valued_input_parameter`, *the list of values must not be empty; it must contain at least one value.*

Comment: You are exactly correct, list of values was having no values and thus caused this issue...